# VS Code Shortcut to Wrap Widget with GetX's Obx

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, flutter-getx

In VS Code on a Mac with Flutter extensions installed, if you hit `Cmd + .` then you will see this popup to wrap a widget:

[image]

Is there a way to customize one of those options? I would like to be able to wrap a widget inside GetX's `Obx` like this:

```
Obx(()=> 
  WIDGET
)
```

Being able to do this would save me a lot of keystrokes.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I didn’t find a way to customise it but I use a snippet expander to accomplish the same thing. I use Atext on a Mac so ;obx would expand to Obx(()=>)

Answer (score 0):

You can use GetX Snippets extension in VS code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Getx Snippets extension/plugin for both `VScode` and `IntelliJ` :

[Getx Snippets extension - VScode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=get-snippets.get-snippets)

[Getx Snippets plugin - IntelliJ](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/14975-getx-snippets)